# How to prevent a iframed page from opening in a new window

Tags: asp.net, iframe, hyperlink, target

I have a site iframed in and it has a bunch of links in the menu. The way their site is built they have all the links in the menu set to open the pages in a new window. Is there any way to override this and have it open in the iframe?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

If you can get around the security issues, I'd suggest looking at jQuery in order to take over the click event for all the links. If your hosted on different domains and don't have control over the local browser your probably out of luck.

Comment: It is hosted on different domains... alright I guess I could see about getting them to change that. Thanks